# java: compiling files with same name but differ in upper and lower case in windows eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I am using eclipse in Windows.

I have two files in the same folder with the same name but differ in upper and lower case:

```
src/dets/controller/DetsServlet.java 
src/dets/controller/DETSServlet.java
```

after I compiled them, only DETSServlet.class appears in my build folder.

If i compile them in Linux, then i can get both of them to compiled.

Does anyone know how I can get both of them to compile in windows eclipse?
It this a windows problem or eclise problem?

I didnt write this code. This was written like 5 years ago and I'm just here to add some improvements. I am using a windows machine and i guess back then the people who wrote this all used linux machines so they didnt have to deal with this problem. This code will be compiled into a library and will be used by different programs, so if i have to change the file name, I have to go to all the other programs and changes their import path.

Comment: But why you want to name a file like this? What's the purpose of it? Isn't it too confusing?

Comment: Why don't you change the name of one of them? Even if you make it work, the two almost identical names would always be a source of confusion to enayone who tried to understand your code.

Comment: The problem is that Windows doesn't generally honor case differences, and will regard the two file names as identical.  This isn't a Java issue.  I think there are settings that will cause Windows to distinguish between cases, but it's messy to do this, at best.  Net-net:  **Don't** use class names that differ from other class names by only the case of the letters.

Answer (score 3):

For whats it worth, that is a Windows platform restriction. Windows is case-insentive when it comes to file names. But, I agree with previous comments: having 2 files in the same package with same name - only different case - is a potential for confusion.